# Arithmetic overflow error for type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm currently getting this error when do a select on a table

Arithmetic overflow error for type int, value = 4318826193.000000.

I'm trying to figure out what column is causing this , what is the best way to figure out what column is causing this problem with this value 4318826193.000000  ?

I've tried writing a select statement with all the INT columns with a CAST( [column name] as bigint) but the error still appears.

```
 SELECT
       CAST(Id AS BIGINT)
      ,CAST (CreatedBy as BIGINT)
      ,CAST (UpdatedBy as BIGINT)
      ,CAST (HeaderId as BIGINT)
      ,CAST (DiskFileId as BIGINT)
      ,CAST (Status as BIGINT)
      ,CAST (TotalLines as BIGINT)
      ,CAST (CompletedLines as BIGINT)
      ,CAST (ProcessedLines as BIGINT)
      ,CAST (PercentComplete as BIGINT)
      ,CAST (SecondsRemaining as BIGINT)
      ,CAST (RollbackUser as BIGINT)
      ,CAST (CreatedRecords as BIGINT)
      ,CAST (UpdatedRecords as BIGINT)
      ,CAST (SkippedRecords as BIGINT)
      ,CAST (DiallerExportProgress as BIGINT)
      ,CAST (idxCampaignId as BIGINT)
      ,CAST (ScheduleId as BIGINT)
      ,CAST (CampaignId as BIGINT)

 from [table_name]
```

Thanks

Comment: what is the RDBMS you are using and version ?

Comment: (1) Edit your question and show the query (perhaps simplified0 that you are using.  (2) Tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: 4318826193 is not a valid int, but bigint should work fine. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Max value of an int is 2.14B.  Go bigint or even decimal(16,0)

Comment: @TheGameiswar SQL and version is 2012

Comment: @jarlh SQL, but the question is how do i find out which column is causing it

Comment: The value cannot be present in the int column of your table. Can you please post the query you are trying to execute?

Comment: As Neeraj says, the column data is valid. You must have an arithmetic expression that overflows. (Or, are you perhaps selecting from a view?)

Comment: what if you start by querying no columns, SELECT 0 from table_name, and if that works, then add them one by one until it breaks - then you have the answer to your question.  Be methodical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Try_convert`,For conversion failures instead of erroring out ,`TRY_Convert` Throws `null`

```
select try_convert(int,4318826193.000000)
```

How to use..

```
Select TRY_CONVERT(BIGINT,DiskFileId)
```

Comment: so in my select statement which im currently doing, how would i use it ?

Comment: Thank you , that was exactly what i needed

Answer (score 0):

you can use max on all the columns and get the maximum value to find which column is producing it.